# Saving list data (or data items) manually for future use

Tags: c#, list, collections

I am debugging a .net(C#) app in VS2013. I am calling a rest service and it returns data as a list of phone calls that have been made between two given dates.
So the structure of List is something like CallDetails.Calls and then Calls property has several child properties like, call duration, timeofcall, priceperminute etc etc.

Since I am debugging the app, I want to avoid every time hitting the server where the rest service is hosted.

So my question is simply that if there is a way that when I have received the List of data items, I (kind of) copy and paste data into a file and later use it in a statically defined List instead of fetching it from the server?

In case someone wonders why would I want to do that, there is some caching of all incoming requests on the server and after a while it gets full so the server does not return data and ultimately a time out error occurs. 
I know that should be solved on the server some how but that is not possible today that is why I am putting this question.

Thanks

Comment: It's perfectly fine to mock things when you're debugging.  In fact, we encourage unit testing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a unit test using MSTest or NUnit. I know unit tests are scary if you haven't used them before, but for simple automated tests they are awesome.  You don't have to worry about lots of the stuff people talk about for "good unit testing" in order to get started testing this one item.  Once you get the list from in the debugger while testing, you could then

1. save it out to a text file,
2. manually (one time) build the code to copy it from the text file,
3. Use that code as the set-up for your test.

MSTest tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182524%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

NUnit is generally considered superior to MSTest, and in particular has a feature that is better for running a set of data through the same test. Based on what you've said, I don't think you need the NUnit test case, but I've never used it.  If you do want it, after the quickstart guide, the keyword to look for is testcase if you want to go that route.  http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html